# Does intellij idea offer auto completion for non getter el methods?

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea

I have auto completion out of the box for getter methods in jsp expression languages with intellij. I don't have it however for non getter methods (part of EL 2.2, which is maintained as part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2).

Idea does however recognise the call to non getter methods in El as valid.

Is there any way to turn auto completion on for the non getter method ?

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [IDEA-115227](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115227) is the issue to add your comments and votes to.

Comment: Indeed, Pakka. The issue was created based on a message I sent to intellij support. Alain